# How to execute a pivot_wider multiple times in R?

Tags: r, pivot, multiple-columns

Below is the sample data and the desired result. The task at hand is to pivot multiple times(or at least I think it is multiple times) in order to create a complete historical series per row. At the moment, each qtr (quarter) is a row. The naming convention is not all that important. I know how to do a pivot_wider but the creating of the monthly column names has me stumped.

```
 area <- c("000000","000000","000000","000000","000003","000003","000003","000003")
 indcode <- c("432100","432100","432100","432100","432100","432100","432100","432100")
 Year <- c("2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019")
 qtr <- c("01","02","03","04","01","02","03","04")
 month1_emplvl <-c(100,101,102,103,44,44,46,52)
 month2_emplvl <-c(100,101,103,104,48,44,52,41)
 month3_emplvl <-c(101,100,102,99,44,45,46,47)

 testdata <- data.frame(area,indcode,Year,qtr,month1_emplvl,month2_emplvl,month3_emplvl)
```

Desired result

```
  area    indcode    2019-01     2019-02   2019-03    2019-04   2019-05   2019-06 and so on...
  000000    432100      100         100        101      101        101        100
  000003    432100       44          48         44       44        44          45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the solution you're looking for (pass all the months to the `values_from` argument)?

```r
df <- pivot_wider(testdata, values_from = c(month1_emplvl, month2_emplvl, month3_emplvl), names_from = c(Year, qtr))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to apply pivoting multiple times, but I think you could use

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

testdata %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("month"), names_pattern = "month(\\d)_*") %>% 
  mutate(
    new_name = 
      paste(Year, 
            str_pad((as.integer(qtr) - 1) * 3 + as.integer(name), 
                    width = 2, 
                    side = "left", 
                    pad = "0"),
            sep = "-"),
    .keep = "unused") %>%   
  pivot_wider(names_from = new_name)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 14
  area  indcode `2019-01` `2019-02` `2019-03` `2019-04` `2019-05` `2019-06` `2019-07` `2019-08`
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 0000~ 432100        100       100       101       101       101       100       102       103
2 0000~ 432100         44        48        44        44        44        45        46        52
# ... with 4 more variables: `2019-09` <dbl>, `2019-10` <dbl>, `2019-11` <dbl>,
#   `2019-12` <dbl>
```

Comment: Gai, I made the sample data very narrow so as to not make it overly complex. However, what if I had multiple industries for every year, qtr, and area combination. What would I group by?